# Выравнивание элемента внутри StackPanel по правому краю

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему четвертая кнопка не выравнивеатся по правому краю?

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внутри горизонтальной `StackPanel` `HorizontalAlignment="..."` не работает — вы как бы делегируете контейнеру задачу расположения элемента внутри себя. Для точного управления направлением выравнивания попробуйте `DockPanel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что элемент `StackPanel` как раз и нужен для того, чтобы все располагать в одну строку (столбец). Его смысл в том, что при изменении размера - сжатии или растяжении - он автоматически переставит все внутренние элементы в заданном порядке (попробуйте поизменять размеры окна, привязав размеры `StackPanel` к размеру окна).

По умолчанию все сдвигает к левому верхнему углу, как бы загоняет их в стек. В нем выравнивание не работает - для этого нужны другие элементы (например `Grid`).